# How can I make function for multiple instances

Tags: jquery

I have written a small code to show hide element and its working fine. What can I do to make it work on multiple instances. How can I make code for multiple instances

```
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8" />
<title>Untitled Document</title>
<style>
.heading{ font-size:18px}
.paragraph{ font-size:12px; height:0; overflow:hidden; background-color:#CCCCCC;}
.close{ color:#FF0000; font-weight:bold;}

</style>
<script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.3.2/jquery.min.js"></script>

</head>
<div>
    <h1 class="heading">This is Heading</h1>
    <p class="paragraph">This is paragraph. This is paragraph. This is paragraph. This is paragraph. This is paragraph. This is paragraph. This is paragraph.<br/><span class="close">Close</span> </p>
</div>
<div>
    <h1 class="heading">This is Heading</h1>
    <p class="paragraph">This is paragraph. This is paragraph. This is paragraph. This is paragraph. This is paragraph. This is paragraph. This is paragraph.<br/><span class="close">Close</span> </p>
</div>

<script>
$('h1.heading').click(function(){
$clickedElement=$(this);
$('$clickedElement.paragraph').animate({'height':'50px'},1000);
})

$('.close').click(function(){
$('.paragraph').animate({'height':'0px'},1000);
})
</script>

</body>
</html>
```

Comment: can I suggest not styling your content to be hidden (aka 0 height) on page load? If the only way to access your content is with javascript if someone has it disabled they will never be able to see it. Since you are already using jQuery just $('.paragraph').hide() in your $(document).ready() and that way it will only be hidden from users if they have javascript enabled.

Comment: Thanks Jeremy you have a valid point.

Answer (score 0):

change your code to this:

```
<script>
    $('h1.heading').click(function(){
    $(this).next().animate({'height':'50px'},1000);
    })

    $('.close').click(function(){
    $('.paragraph').animate({'height':'0px'},1000);
    })
    </script>
```

Comment: Hi Kim thanks for the reply your code is working but if two "paragraphs" are open and I click close its closing both all paragraphs

Comment: Is this the best way to modify it 'code'$('h1.heading').click(function(){
    $(this).next().animate({'height':'50px'},1000);
    })

$('.close').click(function(){
    $(this).parent().animate({'height':'0px'},1000);
    }) 'code'

Answer (score 0):

You *need* a `<body>` tag after `</head>`

Also, You should probably be doing this:

```
$(function() {
  $('h1.heading').click(function(){
    $(this).parent().find('.paragraph').slideDown(1000);
  })

  $('.close').click(function(){
    $(this).parent().slideUp(1000);
  })
});
```

Otherwise those elements will stay visible and overlap in some browsers.

Comment: Thanks Jeremey I modified it a bit and its working <script>
$(function() {
  $('h1.heading').click(function(){
    $(this).parent().find('.paragraph').animate({height:'40px'},1000);
  })

  $('.close').click(function(){
    $(this).parent().parent().find('.paragraph').animate({height:'0px'},1000);
  })
});
</script>